# descending numbers for datatables index column

Tags: laravel, datatables

I need the index column of datatable which use:

```
t.on( 'order.dt search.dt', function () {
        t.column(0, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
            cell.innerHTML = i+1;
        } );
    } ).draw();
```

order desc. Not just in data sorting but in numbers too.
[image]

and the numbers would be from 10 to one.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your problem? I am unable to understand as per provided info.

Comment: As per my assumption, you want that `index column` count should be in `desc` order > https://jsfiddle.net/mmushtaq/odL2wj6r/

Comment: @mmushtaq thx. That was exactly what i needed :)

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by getting `total row count` of the DataTable and decrementing that row count to displaying in index column on `search` and `order`.

```
t.on( 'order.dt search.dt', function () {
       var rows = t.rows().count();
        t.column(0, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
            cell.innerHTML = rows--;
        } );
    } ).draw();
```

> Demo -> [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mmushtaq/odL2wj6r/)

As per my opinion! `Index column` should displaying numbers according to the order of the datatable. If datatable is sorted in `asc` order then `index column` should displaying numbers like that `1,2,....,10` and if the datatable order is `desc` then `index column` should have numbers `10,9,....,1` .

For this functionality, you just need to get current order of the datatable.

```
t.on('order.dt search.dt', function() {
    var rows = t.rows().count();
    var order = t.order();
    t.column(0, {
      search: 'applied',
      order: 'applied'
    }).nodes().each(function(cell, i) {
      if (order[0][1] == "asc")
        cell.innerHTML = i++;
      else
        cell.innerHTML = rows--;
    });
  }).draw();
```

> Demo > [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mmushtaq/gtcepj6x/)